# import spring-boot-starter by myself, start print error log 'Unable to read meta-data for class'

Tags: filenotfoundexception, spring-boot-starter

**hello everybody，  I have a problem with spring-boot-starter.**

**I write some code to implement a starter**

**But not working properly，when start my project**

**idea console print error log:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read meta-data for class com.beiming.zipkin.starter.config.ExampleAutoConfigure
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationMetadata(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:245) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:214) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.access$000(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.lambda$getInPriorityOrder$0(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:63) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.getInPriorityOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:61) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.sortAutoConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:461) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:442) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:881) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:804) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:774) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.teststarter.TestStarterApplication.main(TestStarterApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/beiming/zipkin/starter/config/ExampleAutoConfigure.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationMetadata(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:241) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

I can't understand what this error means.

Next is my code 、config file and dependency:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(ExampleService.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ExampleServiceProperties.class)
public class ExampleAutoConfigure {

  private final ExampleServiceProperties properties;

  @Autowired
  public ExampleAutoConfigure(ExampleServiceProperties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "example.service", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
  ExampleService exampleService() {
    return new ExampleService(properties.getPrefix(), properties.getSuffix());
  }

}

@ConfigurationProperties("example.service")
public class ExampleServiceProperties {

  private String prefix;
  private String suffix;

  public String getPrefix() {
    return prefix;
  }

  public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
  }

  public String getSuffix() {
    return suffix;
  }

  public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
    this.suffix = suffix;
  }
}

public class ExampleService {

  private String prefix;
  private String suffix;

  public ExampleService(String prefix, String suffix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
    this.suffix = suffix;
  }

  public String wrap(String word) {
    return prefix + word + suffix;
  }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class ZipkinSpringBootStarterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZipkinSpringBootStarterApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

here my config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.beiming.zipkin.starter</groupId>
  <artifactId>zipkin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>zipkin-spring-boot-starter</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <!--<proc>none</proc>-->
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>

</project>
```

That all , Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using this starter in another spring-boot application then you need to remove

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

from your pom. It causes your configuration class to be placed under `BOOT-INF/classes/` root inside the jar therefore, your application cannot find it. Here is a more detailed explanation: [Unable to read meta-data for class. Spring autoconfig](http://itzap.com/unable-to-read-meta-data-for-class-spring-autoconfig/)

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem then I changed spring-boot maven plugin to this

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

in general spring-boot maven plugin it creates jar having BOOT-INF folder , if you add exec classifier then it creates jar having starter classes package so that other projects can recognize starter classes. It works in my case .

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to add @AutoConfiguration in your main class, or try to disable remove

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```